# How do I cleanly remove ruby 1.8.7 from CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, ruby, uninstall

How can I cleanly remove my ruby version 1.8.7 from CentOS 5? I installed it by downloading the source code and performed a make.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't install software this way.
Removing software which was installed like this may be **dangerous**:

1. unpack the same ruby to /tmp
2. run:

```
    ./configure --prefix=/tmp/somedir    # by default prefix points to /usr/local
    make
    make install    # this will install ruby in /tmp/somedir instead of where you've installed it
    cd /tmp/somedir
    find . -type f -exec rm -i /usr/local{} \;    # Use without -i if you are shure
    find . -type d -exec rm -ir /usr/local{} \;
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Interesting idea. You could also use the list of files generated in /tmp/somedir and manually remove the bits from the real installation tree. Either way, the fake installation is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try the technique from [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/146511/uninstall-ruby-from-source). Basically look for `.installed.list` in the directory you built ruby in. This should have a list of all the files installed. One way to remove them all would be

```
cat .installed.list | xargs rm
```

Note that this will only delete files, not directories. I guess you could also do

```
cat .installed.list | xargs rmdir
```

after the first command. That should clean up the directories aswell. And `rmdir` will not remove a directory if it still contains files, so it *should* be safe ...

Comment: You may need to run the `cat .installed.list | xargs rmdir` several times to get rid of all the directories it creates.

Comment: Or use something like "cat .installed.list | while read F; do test -f $F && rm -r $F; done"

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
more .installed.list | xargs rm -rfv
```

Answer (score 0):

It will not be easy if you issued configure and make without using --prefix switch, but you can try this way:

1. Extract file list from the RPM database:

   rpm -qla > list1.txt
2. Then find all files from your system

   find / > list1.txt
3. Then diff is your friend:

   diff list1.txt list2.txt > alien_files.txt

In alien_files.txt you'll have the files which weren't installed via rpm (including ruby's). Of course you'll have to filter /proc, /tmp, ... files, but I said that it will not be easy. :)

If you like the RPM philosophy as I do, then read my article on howto install Ruby Enterprise 1.8.7 on CentOS 5 as rpm here:

http://www.cherpec.com/2009/10/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-source-rpm-for-centos5-rhel5/