# centos ruby 1.8.7 repository

Tags: centos, ruby, rpm, repository

I can't find a repository that contains ruby 1.8.7.  All repos only contain 1.8.5 or 1.8.6 versions.

Does anyone know of any repos with ruby-1.8.7?

Comment: You forgot your question.

Comment: What version of centos are you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RBEL Repo](http://rbel.frameos.org/) provides Ruby packages for RHEL based distro's.

Answer (score 1):

I also searched for a more recent ruby for RHEL 5 / centos, nothing found.
Maybe other, recent ruby versions break other things...

Comment: Indeed, it will probably break all extensions compiled against the shipped version of Ruby, so you'll need to recompile extensions and packages that you want to use with it.  RHEL/CentOS usually remains on a single major version of a package to provide ABI stability and compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I can't either but you can still install from rpm.

Here are some links.

[cherpec.com](http://www.cherpec.com/2009/10/ruby-enterprise-edition-1-8-7-source-rpm-for-centos5-rhel5/)

[Previous serverfault.com question](https://serverfault.com/questions/82343/how-do-i-cleanly-remove-ruby-1-8-7-from-centos-5)

Obviously as these are unknown third party sources, you should make your own assessment on the security implications.

Comment: SMiX, How did you finally resolve this. Did you install ruby 1.8.7 from rpm or are you sticking with a version in the repos?

Comment: Based on his later question, itsabear solved it by switching to Ubuntu.

Comment: @Rilindo: I find that solves a lot of problems with CentOS.