# Uninstall ruby from source

Tags: ruby, uninstall, source

I installed ruby 1.9 on my fedora 13 machine from source. I want to go back and use the older 1.8.6 (which I'll install with yum), unfortunetly it appears that I can't simply uninstall my current version by "make uninstall" (`make: *** No rule to make target`uninstall'.  Stop.`).

Is there any way of doing this other than removing each individual file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a file in the build directory called `.installed.list`. This appears to be a list of all the files that get installed.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I ran "cat .installed.list | xargs rm". It could only delete files (not directories - this is what I wanted), which was good enough for me.

Answer (score 1):

If ruby was installed in the following way:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo make install
```

You can uninstall it in the following way:

Check installed ruby version; lets assume 2.1.2

```
wget http://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.1/ruby-2.1.2.tar.bz2
bunzip ...
tar xfv ...
cd ruby-2.1.2
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
make
sudo checkinstall
  # will build deb or rpm package and try to install it
```

After installation, you can now remove the package and it will remove the directories/files/etc.

```
sudo rpm -e ruby
```

There might be some artifacts left:

```
Removing ruby ...
  warning: while removing ruby, directory '/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems' not empty so not removed.
  ...
```

Remove them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the Makefile to see if there's another target such as `remove`.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't look thoroughly, but I couldn't find any such targets..

Comment: There is not...

Answer (score -1):

You can run the following commands:

```
cd ruby-x.x.x (your source code directory)
sudo make uninstall
sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/ruby
```